# Plotting every categorical value of a list matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I think that I have a really easy problem, but I can not come up with a solution...
Consider the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create some mock data
t = ["A" , "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C"]
data1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
data2 = [6,2,8,2,6,8,2]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

color = 'tab:red'
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color=color)
ax1.plot(t, data1, color=color)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

color = 'tab:blue'
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color=color)  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(t, data2, color=color)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)

fig.tight_layout()  # otherwise the right y-label is slightly clipped
plt.show()
```

The resulting image looks like this:
[image]

I want, that on the X-Axis, every element gets displayed seperatly, something like this (without the 1)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use numbers for plotting the x-data and then re-label the x-ticks with your desired categorical values as done in the following

```
xvals = range(len(t)) # This is the actual x-values to be plotted on the x-axis

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

# Remaining code

ax1.plot(xvals, data1, color=color) # Use xvals here
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax1.set_xticks(xvals) # Set the ticks at desired locations
ax1.set_xticklabels(t) # Set the categorical values as tick-labels

# Remaining code

ax2.plot(xvals, data2, color=color) # Use xvals here
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor=color)
ax2.set_xticks(xvals) # Set the ticks at desired locations
ax2.set_xticklabels(t) # Set the categorical values as tick-labels
```

[image]